# select sum column from datatable group by

Tags: c#, datatable

i have datatable with columns

```
transactionid,tenderid,amount,bankcode,CardType
```

i need to select `transactionid,tenderid,Sum(amount),bankcode,CardType` from it group by `transactionid,tenderid,bankcode,CardType`

this is what i reached but i don't know what i should type in select

```
 dttransactiontenders= dttransactiontenders.AsEnumerable()
       .GroupBy(r => new { Col1 = r["transactionid"], Col2 = r["tenderid"], Col3 = r["bankcode"], Col4 = r["CardType"] })
       .Select(g => g.OrderBy(r => r["transactionid"]).First())
       .CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to calculate the sum you can't use the existing `DataRows`, you have to create new. Then you can't use `CopyToDataTable`. Instead you can use this approach:

```
DataTable dtResult = dttransactiontenders.Clone(); // same columns, empty
var query = dttransactiontenders.AsEnumerable()
       .GroupBy(r => new { Col1 = r["transactionid"], Col2 = r["tenderid"], Col3 = r["bankcode"], Col4 = r["CardType"] });

foreach(var g in query)
{
   DataRow addedRow = dtResult.Rows.Add();
   addedRow["transactionid"] = g.Key.Col1;
   addedRow["tenderid"] = g.Key.Col2;
   addedRow["bankcode"] = g.Key.Col3;
   addedRow["CardType"] = g.Key.Col4;
   addedRow["amount"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("amount"));
}
```

If you want to overwrite the old `DataTable` simply assign the new:

```
dttransactiontenders = dtResult;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help